# GRAV CMS - redirection using

Tags: grav

I'm using GRAV CMS on my site and would like to create a news page.
I created the page using the template ready for the Blog, everything was as expected I only have one problem that when I click on the read more I would like to redirect to another page.
Has anyone ever been in this situation?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0eoI.png)

Comment: I'm confused as to what your question is. In the default template, the "Read more" links (note redirect is different) to the actual article. What is your current setup doing and how is that different from what should happen?

Comment: I would like to refer you to another page when I click on read more.

Comment: And what is preventing that from happening? That is demonstrated by the example theme; have you even tried?

Comment: I would like to send it to an external page, it will refer you to the local page with the content of the text.

Comment: Okay... Have you tried changing how that url is generated?

Answer (score 0):

In the YAML header of the page put the following code:

```
external_url: 'http://mywebsite.com/myurl'
```

(do change the URL above)

This will allow you to keep your intro and pictures in the blog, and redirect to the external URL upon visiting that page within Grav.

[Here is the documentation on the feature](https://learn.getgrav.org/15/content/headers#external-url)